# Always getting http status code 200 in Node.js even when there is an error from server

Tags: node.js, http, error-handling

I'm using `Node` as a proxy server between a `React App` and `Microsoft Dynamics Nav`. I make `CRUD` requests in both `OData` and `SOAP` web services. When Dynamics Nav Server responds with an error, I need to show that error in React App. The problem is that I always get a http `200` status code in Node.js, even when I get an error on server (i.e. `404`). This is an example response of a put request, in both Node.js and Postman:

Postman

[image]

Node.js

[image]

This is server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": server started on port 5000");
});

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New connection...');
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Express for courier is working on IISNode!');
});

app.use(require('./routes/routesLogin'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesCustomers'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesContacts'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesPostCodes'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesCountriesRegions'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesDepots'));
app.use(require('./routes/routesPUOrder'));
```

This is the function for a put request:

```
    ModifyPUOrder: function (req, res) {
        console.log('MODIFY');
        const PUOrderNo = req.body.puOrderNo;
        const updatedValue = req.body.updatedValue;
        console.log('MODIFY PU', PUOrderNo);
        console.log('UPDATEDVALUE', updatedValue)
        const url = `${base}/PUOrderCard('${PUOrderNo}')`;

        request =   `{ ${updatedValue} }`;
        
        put(username, password, url, request).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            res.send(response);
        })
    },
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default status code for a response in Express is `200`, you can change this before you call `send`

```
res.status(400).send('Bad request')
```